# At CircleCI when use multiple images gradle isn't accessible

Tags: java, gradle, build, circleci, google-cloud-sdk

I have this yml:

```
 jobs:
     deploy_to_staging:
         docker:
           - image: google / cloud-sdk
           - image: circleci / openjdk: 11-jdk
```

I have access to commands only from the first image, for example when the command `gradle build` runs it returns:

```
 / bin / bash: gradle: command not found
```

If I invert image order then I can access gradle commands but gcloud will not be found.

Does anyone know which is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the Docker executor works. The first image is the primary image, which is the environment where all of your commands run in. The additional images are only connected via TCP/IP.

Comment: Is there a way to run commands from the second image? Or should I put both images into a third image?

Comment: The secondary images are available via TCP/IP. So you can access networked services. Commands won't be run in secondary images, only the primary image. You can't just combine images trivially. I would choose one and extend it with additional tools or just install tools on the fly during the build.